# Can`t load valid .json file, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I`m trying to load .json file with

```
def load_combinations(self):
    if os.path.exists('combinations.json'):
        with open('combinations.json', 'r') as f:
            self.combinations = json.load(f)
    else:
        open('combinations.json', 'x').close()
```

That code give me **json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**, even so my .json is **valid** (I`ve even check it on the site). I tried remove *'r'* or make it *'w'*, get it with *json.loads(f.read())* aaaaand its not working

JSON example:

```
{
    "1": "0234567802345678023456780234567802345678023456780234567802345678",
    "01": "2345678234567823456782345678234567823456782345678",
    "013": "245678245678245678245678245678245678",
    "0134": "2567825678256782567825678",
    "01345": "2678267826782678",
    "012345": "678678678",
    "0123458": "6767",
    "01234578": "6",
    "012345678": ""
}
```

Created by:

```
def save_combinations(self):
    toSave = {}
    for c, i in self.combinations.items():
        string = ''
        for u in i:
            string += str(u)
        toSave[c] = string

    with open('combinations.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(toSave, f, indent=4)  # "0123": "012301230123"
```

Python 3.11.6

Thanks

Comment: That's simply not JSON, simple as that. The last comma would have to be removed for that. BTW: Just search for the error essage please! Also, for a good question, provide a [mcve].

Comment: I searched and no solution came up. The comma is there because I cut out part of the .json, there is no comma in the complete file.

Comment: You need to up your search skills: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=JSONDecodeError%3A+Expecting+value%3A+line+1+column+1+%28char+0%29

Answer (score 0):

Aaaand now its working. I simply asked this question and went to do my uni work... It fixed itself. I didnt change like **anything**. Well, ok, I love writing code...

I think it was Windows/Physical problem (???)

Comment: That error usually indicates that the file is empty. Not sure why it fixed itself, are you sure you didn't download the file in the meantime?

Comment: I didnt touch that project at all. And I checked file like every time i ran the code, its not a problem. 
About "you sure you didn't download the file in the meantime", .json created by my code and at meantime i did download some photo, but they are not related to the project.
Things happen ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Sounds like the problem is not reproducible. In that case, it's off topic and unlikely to help future users, and should likely be deleted. You'll probably have to delete this answer first.